# Setting Three.JS projection matrix parameters

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

For my project I want to manually set projection matrix parameters.

for example I want to be able to be able to do something like this:

```
camera.projectionMatrix[15] = 1;
```

How can I do that in Three.JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
camera.projectionMatrix.elements[15] = 1;
```